# How to handle All minutes for this organization has been exhausted in lamdatest

Tags: javascript, lambda, webdriver-io

I am working on `webdriverIO` project.
In the config file I added user and key and also added capabilities and services like below -

```
capabilities: [
      {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        version: 'latest',
        platformName: 'Windows 10'
      }
]
services: [
        ['selenium-standalone'],
    
        ['lambdatest', {
            tunnel: true
        }]
]
```

AND I am getting the following error -

```
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to WebDriver Error: 
All minutes for this organization has been exhausted
ERROR webdriver: WebDriver Error: All minutes for this organization has been exhausted
ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
All minutes for this organization has been exhausted
```